# How can I avoid return the input argument of lambda in RxJava?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

How can I replace the following code?

```
return Observable.just(player1, player2)
                     .doOnNext(player -> player.status = // mutate status)
                     .flatMap(player -> {
                                 playersDao
                                         .savePlayerCompletable(player)
                                         .andThen(Single.just(player));
                             }
                     )
            ;
```

I don't really like how I pass `player` into that lambda inside of `flatMap` and then I return it in `Single.just`. How can I get around? The idea is that I absolutely have to return that updated players (with different status) in `Observable`. And I don't really want to make `saveReport` to return `Single`.

**EDIT**: I do want to return `Flowable<Player>` as a result (so I don't want to lose them in RxChain).

Comment: What does `andThen` do?

Comment: Waits for `Completable` instance to complete and executes the code inside the block. Basically it's a `Completable.concatArray` that returns non-Completable thing.

Answer (score -1):

Use a flatmap completable.

```
 Throwable throwable = Flowable.fromIterable(players)
                   .doOnNext(request -> request.status == //mutate states)
                                          .flatMapCompletable(savePlayerCompletable::save)
                                              .blockingGet();
    if (throwable != null) {
     ///something went wrong
    }
```

or

```
return Flowable.fromIterable(players)
                   .doOnNext(request -> request.status == //mutate states)
.flatMapCompletable(savePlayerCompletable::save);
```

Comment: Will it return `Flowable<Player>`? I believe `flatMapCompletable` will return a Completable instance and we'll lose our players in that chain. I don't really like using `blockingGet` in non-test environment, either.

Comment: yes it would return a completable ... ah right I got you.